# Altering if-statement condition in consideration of template argument

Tags: c++, templates, cuda

I have a global kernel function with template argument:

```
template<int ARG> __global__ void kernel(array[]) {
    int threadID = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(...) {...}
}
```

The behaviour of the function, and a specially if-statement condition, is slightly varying in consideration of template argument but the body stays the same. Lets say: 
`ARG == 0` if statement looks like: `if(expr1){body}` 
`ARG == 1` if statement looks like: `if(expr2){body}` 
`ARG == 2` if statement looks like: `if(expr1 && expr2){body}`

My question is what is the best way(in a sense of readability and performance) to provide this?

**EDIT:**
Expressions `expr1` and `expr2` are calls to `__device__ boolean` functions, e.g. `fnc1(array[threadID])` and `fnc2(array[threadID])`.

Comment: it depends on what the expressions depend on etc. can't be reasonably answered in the abstract. give concrete example

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I did the edit.

Comment: @DrewDormann. The body of my if-statements is very long as well as if-statements occur few times. Hence, I would get very long code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The straightforward approach is brute force:

```
if ((ARG != 1 || expr1) && (ARG != 0 || expr2)) ...
```

Since ARG is known at compile time, the compiler will generate good code here.

Comment: This assumes that `expr1` is a well-formed expression regardless of `ARG`. This can be non-trivial: is `ARG != 0 || (Foo/ARG) == Bar` well-formed?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an auxiliary class template:

```
template<int ARG>
class IfCondition {
};
```

and specialize it for different values of `ARG`:

```
template<>
class IfCondition<0> {
public:
    static bool Get() {
        return expr1;
    }
};

template<>
class IfCondition<1> {
public:
    static bool Get() {
        return expr2;
    }
};

template<>
class IfCondition<2> {
public:
    static bool Get() {
        return expr1 && expr2;
    }
};
```

Then use it inside your template like this:

```
if (IfCondition<ARG>::Get())
     ...

}
```

The nice thing about it is that, with inlining, it'll be as fast as literally writing `if(expr1) {body}` or `if (expr2) {body}` or whatnot.

*EDIT*

Another way to go is with template function specialization:

```
template<int ARG>
bool ifCondition() { return false; }

template<>
bool ifCondition<0>() { return expr1; }

template<>
bool ifCondition<1>() { return expr2; }

template<>
bool ifCondition<2>() { return expr1 && expr2; }

// Then later, inside your template:
if (ifCondition<ARG>()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ARG == 0 if statement looks like: if(expr1){body}
>
> ARG == 1 if statement looks like: if(expr2){body}
>
> ARG == 2 if statement looks like: if(expr1 && expr2){body}

Code that directly, since that's your own interpretation of *readable*.

It will be performant since `ARG` can be resolved at compile time.

```
if ( ARG == 0 && expr1 ) {body}

if ( ARG == 1 && expr2) {body}

if ( ARG == 2 && expr1 && expr2 ) {body}
```

Or, if `{body}` is heavy, combine them.

```
if ( ARG == 0 && expr1 ) ||

   ( ARG == 1 && expr2) ||

   ( ARG == 2 && expr1 && expr2 ) {body}
```